# OAuth2.0 generation of token

Tags: rest, oauth, postman

I have recently embarked on the implementation of OAuth2 within a RESTful API, aiming to generate a token for ongoing development. While conducting POST requests using Postman, I encountered difficulties in generating the token successfully.

Currently, my POST request is configured as follows:

Endpoint:

> https://auth.smaapis.de/oauth2/token

Body Parameters (x-www-form-urlencoded):

> grant_type: client_credentials

> client_id: trevi_api

> client_secret: myownpassword

Upon executing this request, I am consistently receiving a "400 Bad Request" response, accompanied by the following error code:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_client",
    "error_description": "Invalid client credentials"
}
```

I am reaching out for guidance and assistance in identifying the root cause of this issue. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Is `trevi_api` the client ID given to you by the API vendor? These are typically a UUID or numeric ID.

Comment: Yes, The vendor provided me with the ID "trevi_api"

Comment: Did they provide you with both, client_id and client_password? Both values should be configured on their side.

Comment: The error suggests that your `client_id` or `client_secret` are wrong.

Comment: Yep they provided me a client_id and client_secret.